# Cut from rope animation, pure CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to create an animation that simulates a "cut from rope" sort of effect.

Picture an object hanging from two ropes.  First, the left one is cut, and a bit after the right one is then cut.  I have got pretty close to the desire effect, but my animation isn't as smooth as I would like.

You can see that the object sort of bounces back up, which I tried to minimize by translating the entire object down.

My question is, is there a better way to achieve this effect, or any ways to improve my animation?

HTML

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS

```
#box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  margin: 100px;
  animation: ropecut 1.2s 1 ease-out;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateZ(0);
  transform-origin: top left;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(50px)
}

#bottom {
  width: 600px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

@keyframes ropecut {
        0% {transform: rotateZ(0deg);transform-origin: top right;animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
    50% {transform: rotateZ(-7.5deg);transform-origin: top right;animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
  70% {transform: rotateZ(-7.5deg);transform-origin: top right;animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
    100% {transform: rotateZ(0);transform-origin: top left;animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;transform: translateY(50px)}
}
```

[Link to JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLmrh7t0/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I basically just took out the `70%` bit of the `keyframe` and then removed the `rotateZ` in the `100%` sequence. That will keep the bottom left corner where it should stay.

```css
#box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  margin: 100px;
  animation: ropecut 1.2s 1 ease-out;
  transform: rotateZ(0);
  transform-origin: top left;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(50px)
}

#bottom {
  width: 600px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

@keyframes ropecut {
        0% {transform: rotateZ(0deg);transform-origin: top right;animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
    50% {transform: rotateZ(-7.5deg);transform-origin: top right;animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
  100% {animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; transform-origin: top right;}
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```